# Rewire Metal Halide Security Light to Use Standard Bulb

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, security, rewire

I have a Utilitech AHR100-00 http://www.lowes.com/pd_319896-33229-AHR100-00_0__?productId=3435358&Ntt=utilitech+security+light&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dutilitech%2Bsecurity%2Blight&facetInfo=

This the second one I have had and both failed in the same manner - they start turning themselves off and on all night.  I have read this is a ballast problem.

I would like to rewire it to use a standard bulb.  I have the following in mind:  Disconnect the capacitor from the black wire between the supply and photocell, disconnect the white wires to the capacitor, ballast and ignitor, and connect the red wire exiting the photo cell to the black wire entering the lamp socket.

Will this work or am I missing something?

Manual with wiring diagram:  http://pdf.lowes.com/useandcareguides/845473031966_use.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have it right. Remember that capacitors can store power for some time, so be careful when handling. I would recommend removing the ignitor, capacitor, and ballast to ensure some future user does not attempt to incorrectly re-wire the fixture. Remember, safety first: turn off and secure the power supply prior to servicing.